# При нажатии кнопки не копирует текст LineEdit в Label

Tags: qt

```
My_Window::My_Window(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
QPushButton *set_text_button=new QPushButton(this);
QLabel *text_label=new QLabel(this);
QLineEdit *line_edit=new QLineEdit(this);
QHBoxLayout *main_layout=new QHBoxLayout(this);
set_text_button->setText("Set Text");
text_label->setText("0");
line_edit->setText("0");
main_layout->addWidget(set_text_button);
main_layout->addWidget(line_edit);
main_layout->addWidget(text_label);
temp_text=line_edit->text();
QObject::connect(set_text_button,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(slot_send_text()));
QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(signal_send_text(QString)),text_label,SLOT(setText(QString)));
setWindowTitle("Changing text on label");
}
void My_Window::slot_send_text()
{
emit (signal_send_text(temp_text));
}
```

При нажатии кнопки текст label-а должен быть таким же, как текст lineedit-а, но этого почему-то не происходит

Comment: Слишком сложно пытаетесь решить проблему: ваш слот может устанавливать текст, а не дергать другой сигнал. Возможно, есть основания делать так как вы делаете, но попробуйте более простой.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но все же почему мой изначальный способ не работал?

Comment: Ну надо в отладчике или через printf выводить temp_text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откуда в вашем слоте `slot_send_text()` берётся значение переменной temp_text?
Попробуйте переписать слот следующим образом:

```
emit (signal_send_text(line_edit->text()));
```

Или так (может более понятно будет):

```
temp_text = line_edit->text();
emit (signal_send_text(temp_text));
```